# conda Solving environment: failed

Tags: anaconda, conda, environment

**Any conda command returns this message**
also tried reinstalling anaconda. Any help is appreciated. 
Any conda command generates the same output.

```
$ conda upgrade conda

Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 280, in recv_into
        return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1715, in recv_into
        self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1521, in _raise_ssl_error
        raise WantReadError()
    OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 280, in recv_into
        return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1715, in recv_into
        self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1538, in _raise_ssl_error
        raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
    OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (54, 'ECONNRESET')

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 601, in read_chunked
        chunk = self._handle_chunk(amt)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 557, in _handle_chunk
        value = self._fp._safe_read(amt)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 612, in _safe_read
        chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 296, in recv_into
        return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 285, in recv_into
        raise SocketError(str(e))
    OSError: (54, 'ECONNRESET')

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 745, in generate
        for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 432, in stream
        for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 626, in read_chunked
        self._original_response.close()
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 320, in _error_catcher
        raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(54, \'ECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 789, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 14, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 236, in install
        force_reinstall=context.force,
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 504, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 437, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 178, in solve_final_state
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 560, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 213, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = query_all(spec)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 186, in query_all
        return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/repodata.py", line 90, in query
        self.load()
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/repodata.py", line 134, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/repodata.py", line 202, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/repodata.py", line 402, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        timeout=timeout)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 658, in send
        r.content
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 823, in content
        self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
      File "/Users/kireto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 748, in generate
        raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(54, \'ECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

`$ /Users/kireto/anaconda3/bin/conda upgrade conda`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/Users/kireto/anaconda3
                     PATH=/Users/kireto/anaconda3/bin:/Users/kireto/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frame
                          works/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/
                          usr/sbin:/sbin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/kireto/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/kireto/.condarc
          conda version : 4.4.10
    conda-build version : 3.4.1
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       base environment : /Users/kireto/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
          package cache : /Users/kireto/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/kireto/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/kireto/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/kireto/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.4.10 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Darwin/17.7.0 OSX/10.13.6
                UID:GID : 503:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
Upload did not complete
```

I tried to look at my .condarc file and even removed it but it doesn't change the outcome. Do you know what I can do to go back to a working conda?

```
conda version : 4.4.10
conda-build version : 3.4.1
```